# evaluating some limits - calculus

Tags: calculus

Problems with the following limits:

$$
1. \quad \quad  \lim_{x\to0^+} e^{1/x} + \ln x \, .
$$

Substitutions such as $e^{1/x}=t$ and $1/x = t$ don't yield any useful results.

Pretty much the same with
$$
2. \quad \quad \lim_{x\to 0^+} e^{1/x} - 1/x \, ,
$$
Common denominator doesn't help much.

Thanks.

Comment: Set $z=1/x
 $ and use the fact that $\ln\left(1/z\right)=-\ln\left(z\right)
 $. Then, use that the exponential dominates the logarithm when $z\rightarrow+\infty
 $.

Comment: It seems like the substitution $t=\frac 1x$ would be very useful, since we could compare $e^t$ with $-\ln t$ at that point and find that no matter what bound $M$ we choose, there exists $t$ such that $e^t-\ln t\gt M$...  Similar process for the second problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure that I allowed to use these kind of arguments. Sure, one can say that $\ln x = O(e^{x})$ as $x\to \infty $ etc... But I'm looking for more constructive solution. 

Thanks.

Comment: Use L'Hôpital's rule to prove that $\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty}\dfrac{e^t}{\ln{t}}=+\infty.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you accept that $\ln u\lt u$ for all $u$, it follows that $\ln(1/x)\lt1/x$, hence

$$e^{1/x}-1/x\lt e^{1/x}-\ln(1/x)=e^{1/x}+\ln x$$

Consequently, it suffices to show

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}(e^{1/x}-1/x)=\infty$$

Now we certainly have $\lim_{x\to0^+}e^{1/x}=\infty$.  Let's write

$$e^{1/x}-1/x=e^{1/x}\left(1-{1/x\over e^{1/x}} \right)$$

and take a look at

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(1-{1/x\over e^{1/x}} \right)=1-\lim_{x\to0^+}{1/x\over e^{1/x}}=1-\lim_{x\to0^+}{-1/x^2\over(-1/x^2)e^{1/x}}=1-\lim_{x\to0^+}{1\over e^{1/x}}=1-0=1$$

This feeds into the general theorem that if $\lim f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim g(x)\gt0$, then $\lim f(x)g(x)=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For $2)$: $e^{1/x} - 1/x > 1 + 1/x^2 \to +\infty$, and for $1)$ $e^{1/x} + \ln x = e^{1/x} - \ln\left(1/x\right)> 1 + 1/x + 1/x^2 - \left(1/x - 1\right)> 1/x^2 \to +\infty$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0^+} e^{\frac{1}{x}} +\ln x& = \lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} +\ln x}{\frac{1}{x}}\\
&= \lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}} +\ln x}{\frac{1}{x}}\\
&= \lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\frac{-1}{x^2}e^{\frac{1}{x}} + \frac{1}{x}}{\frac{-1}{x^2}}\\
&= \lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \lim \limits _{x\rightarrow 0^+} e^{\frac{1}{x}}  -x\\
&=+\infty
\end{align*}
The second one is like the first one.

Answer (score -2):

first let us show that $$  \lim_{u \to \infty} \frac{\ln u}{e^u} = 0$$ this follows because $$ \ln u < u < \frac{u^2}{2} < e^u \text{ so that } \frac{\ln u}{e^u} < \frac{2u}{u^2} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } u \to \infty. $$
let us make a change of variable $u = \frac 1 x, x = \frac 1 u.$ with that we nee to find the $$\lim_{u\to \infty} e^u - \ln u = \lim_{u \to \infty}e^u\left(1- \frac{\ln u}{e^u}\right) =\infty \times 1 = \infty. $$

Comment: Thank you. I guess the second limit can be solved using the same reasoning to show that $\ln t = O(t)$ as $t\to\infty $.

Comment: @user230329, you are welcome. glad to be of some help to you.